# How to get childnode value & change value

Tags: javascript, parent-child, traversal, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

How can I use JavaScript (no JQuery) to traverse through a bunch of DIVs that has a common class, then check the value within the `<span>` tag, base on the value, change the href value to something else. Here is an example mark-up.

```
<div class="module-content">
<div class="js-tab-content S00">
    <h2 class="heading">
        <a href="http://someurl.com">
            <span>Adelaide</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="js-tab-content N00">
    <h2 class="heading">
        <a href="http://anotherurl.com">
            <span>Sydney</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="js-tab-content V00">
    <h2 class="heading">
        <a href="http://thisurl.com">
            <span>Melbourne</span>
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tabContentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tab-content");

for (var i = 0, tabContentDiv; tabContentDiv = tabContentDivs[i]; ++i) {
    var spanEl = tabContentDiv.querySelector(".heading span");
    var spanText = spanEl.innerText;

    var aEl = tabContentDiv.querySelector(".heading a");
    aEl.href += "#" + spanText; // for example
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Can it be more specific with targeting the span within the 'heading' class, as there is a few spans within each DIV, but I excluded them as the example mark-up would be too lengthy.

Comment: Thanks for that, but what about the last 2 lines, so instead of appending the spanText value to the end of the url, how can I check if the spanText is 'Adelaide', change href to http://www.foo.com instead. Is there a more elegant way to do it if I had 12 tabContentDiv, consequently having 12 if statement checking the value of spanText. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Domenic: If you're using `querySelector`, why not use `querySelectorAll('.js-tab-content .heading a span')`? Then in the loop, you can just do: `tabContentDiv.parentNode.href = this.innerText;`.

Comment: @patrick thanks for your comment, i've figured out solution based on comments below, but was wondering if there was a more consist/elegant way to do it. Heres my example: http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/seZdA/

Comment: @caleb: It would be cleaner to create a map of names to hrefs. [In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/seZdA/3/) I directly selected the `span` elements using `querySelectorAll`. Whether or not you take that approach will depend on which browsers you're supporting. `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported by IE8 but `qSA` isn't supported by Firefox 3 (which probably doesn't matter so much at this point).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tab-content");
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    var div = divs[i];
    if(!div) break;
    var span = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var link = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    if(span[0].innerHTML == "Adelaide") link[0].href = "http://google.com";
}
```